# OnDestroy() & OnApplicationQuit() in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is scenario and use cases of `OnDestroy()` and `OnApplicationQuit()` functions in unity? When does we use `OnDestroy()` function and when `OnApplicationQuit()` function?

Comment: OnDestroy : called on object which is going to be destroyed .OnApplication Quit called when you destroy,close game.

Comment: Well I know the definition, but i want to know the real time example of these....

Comment: The use case is mainly closing threads if you used them. People talk about them being used for things like save before quit functions, but honestly that kind of logic has no place in those handlers.

Comment: Did you read the API? They are completely different and unrelated to each other ... `OnDestroy` is called when this specific object is destroyed .. there might be many reasons for that like scene change, it actually was destroyed etc ... `OnApplicationQuit` is called if your app is quit .. there are cases when both behave the same way since also `OnDestroy` is called on all currently existing objects in the scene when `OnApplicationQuit` is called. None of them might be called if your ab crashes ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine by their name, those are functions built to handle executable code only at certain intervals of time in a script's life cycle. Between the two methods, the main difference is **when** they occur. And I quote from the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html):

> OnDestroy occurs when a Scene or game ends. Stopping the Play mode when running from inside the Editor will end the application. As this end happens an OnDestroy will be executed. Also, if a Scene is closed and a new Scene is loaded the OnDestroy call will be made.

While, on the other hands, `OnApplicationQuit()`, as you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html), is

> Sent to all GameObjects before the application quits.

How and when to use these, it comes by itself, it is quite simple to imagine. In example, think when you want to save or record a score or the status of a player, it wouldn't be my first choice, but, you can save it when the application is about to close, so using `OnApplicationQuit()`. To use an example for the `OnDestroy()`, you can imagine having an object `enemy` and when you call an `enemy.Destroy()` and you want to assign points to the player. Those are just small examples, but to be sure to understand a script's life cycle, I suggest you to check [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), where you can find the following interesting and complete image, as well as a complete description of that cycle.

[image: Script's life cycle]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the scenario should be - When you close application a popup ask you to, Do you really want to quit from app? and we can call this in OnApplicationQuit() function.

and for OnDistroy() function we can close opened file or save game state etc....

Comment: Very summarily, yes, it's like this. Anyway, keep in mind that you're talking of a **script**. Those I have done, however, are just examples to make it easier for you to understand

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy is mean when you need to destroy GameOjbect you can call this func like when the player trigger enter the GameOjbect and the GameOjbect is need to destroy then the program would call this func one time.

OnApplicationQuit() is mean  when the player or user need to quit the application , the func will sent to all GameObjects before the application quits.